# Error on if statement when using unchecked

Tags: c#, if-statement, statements

```
 if (Catz = unchecked)
```

It shows an error after the `")"` at the end of this statement. I have the whole statement written out and it shows no other errors besides asking for another `")"`.

Is there an issue with using unchecked? 
NOTE: I have a checkbox that I'm using for this if statement.

Comment: Hover over `unchecked` and see what the error is saying. `unchecked` is a reserve word and it expects a context. The other thing is that to check equality use `==`

Comment: [unchecked is a keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx); `Catz = unchecked` does not make sense syntactically. Are you trying to use it as a variable? Or are you trying to really do something with overflow checking?

Comment: im using the if statement to perform actions based of if the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: Is `Catz` the name of your checkbox?

Comment: Yes it is that's what im trying to determine the result of

Comment: the more information you supply the better answers you get. And people get less confused when trying to help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
if (Catz.Checked)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

If I understood you correctly and `Catz` is a `CheckBox` then the property you
are looking for is probably `Checked`. This can be `true` or `false`
In an `if` statement you can use the `bool` variable without a comparison operator like "=="

to check for the opposite use the "!" negation operator:

```
// if UNCHECKED / NOT CHECKED
if (!Catz.Checked)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in the code you show:

1) `=` is for assignment, `==` is for checking equality. You have `=` when you should be using `==`.

2) `unchecked` is a keyword in C#. You can use keywords as variable names if you prepend an `@` to it:

```
if (Catz == @unchecked)
```

It's easier to just use an unreserved variable name though.